# Global variable not working?

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to make a basic coin flipper and i want a means to repeating it once done, so i added the answer variable and if it == y then it will repeat my main function.
But in while(answer == "y"): it is saying that answer is not defined even though i have globalised the variable?

```
import random


def main():
    myVar = random.randint(1,2)
    if myVar == "2":
        print("Heads")
    else:
        print("Tails")
    global answer
    answer = input("repeat?")

while(answer == "y"):
    main()


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop must be after you call the main() function. Even though you have defined the function before the while loop, it isn't run before you call it.

```
main()
while(answer == "y"):
    main()
```

Also, the result will also always be "Tails", since you check if myVar == "2", which is a string. And myVar is never a string in this case. Remove the quotes to check integer value.

```
if myVar == 2:
```